# AddToTail function in doubly linked list causes core dump

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list, coredump

I am currently trying to write a doubly linked list class in c++ language on cygwin64. My addToTail function (to add a node to the end of the list) causes a core dump. I have identified the line of code which does it but cannot work out why.

I have peeled back my code to the simplest form to work out where the problem is. I have identified it as the `current->setNext(temp);` line.

below is all relevant code

```
class Node
{
    private: 
    classType data;
    Node* next;
    Node* previous;

    public:
    void Node::setData(const valueType& newData)
    {
        data = newData;
    }

    void Node::setNext(Node* newNext)
    {
        next = newNext;
    }

    void Node::setPrevious(Node* newPrevious)
    {
        previous = newPrevious;
    }
};
```

```
class LinkedList
{
    private:
    Node* tail;
    Node* head;
    Node* current;

    public:
    void LinkedList::addToTail(const classType& newTail)
    {
        Node* temp = new Node;
        temp->setData(newTail);
        current = tail;
        temp->setPrevious(current);
        current->setNext(temp);
        tail = temp;
        delete temp;
    }
};
```

The expected results of the function is to add a new Node onto the end of the list. What happens is it causes a core dump.

Answer (score 1):

(I assume that `LinkedList` has valid constructors, and assignment operators no shown in the question. If it lacks those, then `addToTail` treads on undefined behavior from the the start)

> ```
> public:
> void LinkedList::addToTail(const classType& newTail)
> {
>     Node* temp = new Node;
>     temp->setData(newTail);
>     ...
>     tail = temp;
>     delete temp;
> }
> ```

The last delete makes no sense. It deletes `temp`, which is the same as deleting `tail` since `tail` is still accessible from LinkedList. It will trigger undefined behavior the next time addToTail is called, since it will access the deleted tail here:

> ```
>     temp->setData(newTail);
> ```